# Receiving SQL error with DATEDIFF

Tags: mysql, datediff

I am trying to make a DATEDIFF counting the days between pdate and mdate; then displaying it as ddate.  I am receiving errors "Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT contacts DATEDIFF(2014-07-22,2014-07-22)' at line 2".  What exactly is wrong in my code?

```
<?php $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xxx","xxx","xxxx"); // Check connection 
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
 {   
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); 
 }

// escape variables for security 
$pdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pdate']); 
$mdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['mdate']); 
$amt = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['amt']); 
$first = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['first']); 
$last = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['last']); 
$pid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pid']); 
$cno = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['cno']); 
$madd = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['madd']); 
$bene = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['bene']); 
$swc = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['swc']); 
$bacc = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['bacc']); 
$bank = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['bank']); 
$badd = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['badd']); 
$bno = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['bno']);

$sql="INSERT INTO contacts (pdate, mdate, amt, first, last, pid, cno,madd, bene, swc, bacc, bank, badd, bno, ddate) VALUES ('$pdate','$mdate','$amt','$first','$last','$pid','$cno','$madd','$bene','$swc','$bacc','$bank','$badd','$bno','$ddate')";

$sql.="SELECT contacts DATEDIFF($pdate,$mdate) AS ddate";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) 
{   
 die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
} 

echo "Client record has been added to the database!";

mysqli_close($con); 
?>
```

Comment: What is `contacts` doing in the `DATEDIFF` statement? Definitely looks wrong to me

Comment: I apologize, but I am fairly new to MySQL. 
I thought I needed to input the table name into SELECT before using the DATEDIFF.  I am still getting the same error after I removed it.

Comment: You are getting difference between 2 variables so it is independent of the table. Also, the syntax is wrong even for selecting from a table.

Comment: Should I be using [code]SELECT *,DATEDIFF(pdate,mdate) FROM contacts instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to have a table reference in a select query, so the following should work, providing the $pdate and $mdate variables are defined and have date values:

SELECT DATEDIFF($pdate,$mdate) AS ddate

Also, you're combining this query with the previous insert, so you'll need a semi-colon at the end of the insert.